# Is there any SDK available for Iphone so that we can show adds via push notification?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, addition

In android we have Air push , using which we can send and show add via push notification. Is there any thing similar we have for iPhone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advertising by use of push notifications are explicitly forbidden by Apple: according to section 2.2 of the APN terms and conditions:

> You may not use the APN or Local Notifications for the purposes of
>   advertising, product promotion, or direct marketing of any kind (e.g.
>   up-selling, cross-selling, etc.), including, but not limited to,
>   sending any messages to promote the use of Your Application or
>   advertise the availability of new features or versions.

Technically you can do it by rolling your own push notification server or by signing up with one of the established APN providers, e.g. Urban Airship. But I doubt your App will be approved by Apple if you use it for sending ads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use same Urban Airship for Push Notification for iphone too...

Comment: I dont think Urban Airship is used for showing advertisement?